# ActionBar icons not visible

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-menu

I am adding icons to ActionBar, but instead of getting them on ActionBar, I get them in the menu option..

My Java Code-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.report) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Report",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My dashboard.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Share on Whatsapp"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/medication"
    android:title="My Medications"
    android:icon="@drawable/medication"
    app:showAsAction="always"/> 

  <item
    android:id="@+id/coc"
    android:title="Add Circle of care"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"/> 

 <item
    android:id="@+id/report"
    android:title="Report"
    android:icon="@drawable/report"
    app:showAsAction="always"/> 

 </menu>
```

Please tell what am I missing.. 
I have appcompat as library.
Thank you

Comment: Are you extending ActionBar or AppCompactActivity

Comment: I am extending activity

Answer (score 1):

Extended ActionBar or AppCompactActivity

Comment: On extending ActionBarActivity, it says you need to use Theme.Appcompat.. Even when I am using theme.appcompat.... And extending AppCompatActivity, AppCompatActivity can not be resolved to type

Comment: are you using support library

Comment: <style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> you need create theme like this and apply it to activity in manifest

Answer (score 0):

First menu item has `app:showAsAction="never"`, so others menu items will always be shown only in overflow menu.

Comment: You have enough reputation, please add comment for short answers and I tried to use "always" there... still no use

Comment: OK, try return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); instead of return true; in onCreateOptionsMenu.